# How to resolve: Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../../VAADIN/ vaadinBootstrap.js in Vaadin on Grails

Tags: grails, vaadin7

I'm new in Grails and Vaadin. I'd like to use Vaadin in my Grails application. After installing vaadin plugin, when I try start my application I receive this communicat:

```
Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../../VAADIN/ vaadinBootstrap.js
```

I use GGTS-3.6.0.RELEASE, vmware vfabric tc server developer edition v2.9 and Grails-2.4.2. I tried change in `/MyApp/target/work/resources/web.xml` to:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

My layout template:

bootstrap-main.gsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap-responsive.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap-responsive.min.css')}" type="text/css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
    href="/VAADIN/themes/reindeer/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
    href="/VAADIN/themes/reindeer/favicon.ico" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js"></script>
        <r:external uri="/js/jquery.js"/>
        <r:external uri="/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <r:external uri="/js/bootstrap.js"/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <g:javascript library="application"/>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately probably server all the time override my changes. Could you help me?

I don't know what can be helpful else..

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I have had the same issue few days ago. In my case, exactly same message is shown in Vaadin 7 (with a pure Java application). At the end, it was an issue with permissions of tomcat. If I execute tomcat as `root`, it works perfectly. If it is executed with user `tomcat` the message `Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./VAADIN/ vaadinBootstrap.js` is shown again. Of course, we do not want to execute tomcat as root, but it points clearly to the issue.

I know that is maybe not related to the use of `Grails` as the asker is using, but maybe it is also a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify your `web.xml` and have your changes kept between restarts then use the Grails command `install-templates` to install the templates, which includes the `web.xml`. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html).

This file will be located under `src/templates/war`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I modified `web.xml` in `src/templates/war` and changes appears in my `web.xml`, but unfortunately all the time I have the same problem with: `Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../../VAADIN/ vaadinBootstrap.js`. I don't know where is a problem

Comment: You are going to have to provide further details about where that is happening, include the GSP or Layout template that is including it, or any relevant asset configurations.